# Fastest way to search and replace in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I'm building a library that cleans up user generated content and have thousands of string replacements to make (performance is key).

What's the **fastest** way to do search and replacements in strings?

Here's an example of the replacements the library will make:

```
u2 => you too
2day => today
2moro => tomorrow
2morrow => tomorrow
2tomorow  => tomorrow
```

There are four cases on how the string can appear:

- Starting word in the string (has a space at the end, but not in front of it) `2day sample`
- Middle of the string (has a space in front and at the end of it) `sample 2day sample`
- End of the string (only has a space in front, but is the last word) `sample 2day`
- The entire string is a match `2day`

i.e. The regex **shouldn't** replace it if it's in the middle of a word like `sample2daysample`

Comment: Something like `/\b2day\b/`?

Comment: @Aguardientico Thanks for putting me to shame, dude! I didn't know about `\b`

Comment: But now you know so...

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```
replaces = {'u2' => 'you too', '2day' => 'today', '2moro' => 'tomorrow'}

str = '2day and 2moro are u2 sample2daysample'

#exp = Regexp.union(replaces.keys)  #it is the best but to use \b this should be a quiet different
exp = Regexp.new(replaces.keys.map { |x| "\\b" + Regexp.escape(x) + "\\b" }.join('|'))
str = str.gsub(exp, replaces)

# => "today and tomorrow are you too sample2daysample"
```

Answer (score 1):

Full Disclosure: I am the author of this gem

If you don't need regex you can try https://github.com/jedld/multi_string_replace this uses the aho-corasick algorithm to achieve this.

```
                         user     system      total        real
multi gsub           1.322510   0.000000   1.322510 (  1.344405)
MultiStringReplace   0.196823   0.007979   0.204802 (  0.207219)
mreplace             0.200593   0.004031   0.204624 (  0.205379)
```

The only issue I see is that the algorithm does not understand word boundaries so you have to decompose your use case to:

"2day ", " 2day ", " 2day"